# Need to get rid of some warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

I have a alert view that has a text field inside of it. Here is the code:

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];
[myAlert addTextFieldWithValue:nil label:@"Type Password"];
[[myAlert textField] setSecureTextEntry:YES];
[[myAlert textField] setDelegate:self];
[[myAlert textField] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[[myAlert textField] becomeFirstResponder];
[myAlert show];
[myAlert release];
myAlert = nil;
```

I get 4 warnings, each on the lines that include `[[myAlert textField]`. The warnings I get are "Method `-addTextFieldWithValue:label:` not found (return type defaults to 'id')" and "`Method '-textField'` not found (return type defaults to 'id')." What should I do to fix these? Is there a better way to display a text field within an alert view without any warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your warnings is that the `UIAlertView` class doesn't have any such methods as `addTextFieldWithValue` or `textField`.

Generally speaking, alert views are not intended for input, other than allowing a choice between a few basic options ("yes/no", "ok/cancel", etc). If you need a user to type in a password, your text field should be somewhere on a regular view. It is for exactly this reason the kind of methods you are after are not implemented in `UIAlertView`.

For reference: [`UIAlertView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Comment: @Preston: You're using undocumented properties and methods on UIAlertView, which is what @Mac implies but does not explicitly say.

They may actually work, but your app is likely to be rejected by Apple for using them.

(They're warnings because the public header you're using doesn't include them, so the compiler flags it for you. The actual object probably does support those things, which is why it doesn't blow up at runtime.)

Comment: @quixoto: +1 and thanks for the comment - I had no idea that those methods were actually present but undocumented! Learn something new every day... :) Also, good point about using such techniques being a cause for application rejection. Using undocumented APIs also makes maintaining and debugging of apps much more difficult (as demonstrated by the question). @Preston: simple message: try to avoid doing things in unusual ways if at all possible!